# How to access ViewModel that is registered with MainActivity in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

Android documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel details the creation and remember/retrieval of `ViewModel` instance that is registered with `MainActivity`.

My question is - how can I access this `viewModel` instant from other `ViewModel` or from `@Compose` function?

I have tried code

```
private val sessionViewModel: SessionViewModel by viewModels()
```

both in my classes descending from `ViewModel` and in `@Composable` functions, but `viewModels()` function is not available there.

He is how I have done registration:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //...
    val sessionViewModel: SessionViewModel by viewModels<SessionViewModel>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a Composable, you would access you viewModel like this:

```
    @Composable
    fun MyScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
    ) {
    // use viewModel here
    }
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel)

As far as I know, you cannot access a viewModel from another viewModel, but see comment from Martin Marconcini below.

Comment: "you cannot access a viewModel from another viewModel" you can, but you need to inject it. Imagine you could have a `sharedVM` and then individual VM for each "fragment" (for e.g.). In Compose world, I haven't tried this, but I don't see how it wouldn't work (especially when using Hilt) as you could have an activity scoped VM and then individual composeVMs that take the activity VM as a parameter. (I could see some use-cases where that would be convenient, but I'd probably not do it that way unless I know why I'm really going in that direction).